# PHP: ob_start('ob_gzHandler') return illegal character under linux

Tags: php, linux

With the use of ob_gzhandler we get under linux an illegal charaker error at the browser (firefox and chrome).
With windows everything is fine.

Short explanation:
We collect some javascript files in an array ($str_output)

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

header ("Content-Type: text/javascript");

$str_ouptput = array();

foreach ($base_scripts as $script) {        
    $str_output[]  = file_get_contents($script);
}

echo implode(' ', $str_output);
ob_end_flush();
```

At the browser the returned file contains only mashine code and the response header contains:

```
Cache-Control       must-revalidate; max-age: 2592000
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type        text/javascript
```

Without ob_gzhandler everything works fine.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely, the problem is not Linux, but either a BOM issue or a difference in the configurations. Can you give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), i.e. a complete code that always fails? And what Linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It was a home made problem.

In my php.ini was following set

```
php_value output_handler ob_gzhandler
```

It was solved by deleting this line.